# Custom access role in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

i'm new in oracle apex. I want to make a custom authorization based on the user role (manager or employee). I have make an UI for the manager to custom the access role based on the user role when the user click on the checkbox and when click save button (not working for now), the user must be able to access the form based on their access. Anyone know how to do that? Please help. Thank you

[The custom access form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBteO.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question, hard to answer in a single answer. I can give you some form of direction but not a detailed answer:

This is a form of a roles/responsibilities implementation. A user gets a role (employee) but in the application every functionality is tied to a responsibility (eg time sheet, user profile). This is one way to implement this:

- create a user/role mapping table. A user has a row for every role he has, eg User "John" has role "Employee"
- create a role/responsibility mapping table. One row for every responsibility that is granted to a role. This table will be populated from the screen that you posted the screenshot for
- create one authorization scheme in the application for every responsibility you create (one for time sheet, one for user profile, etc). In this authorization scheme you check if there is a row for the current user joined to the user/role mapping table and to the role/responsibility mapping table

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I have make a table for create user mapping table. How to do the authorization scheme? @Koen Lostrie

Comment: Hard to answer that question with the limited amount of info I have available. I suggest you file another question with as much info as possible so I can give you a proper answer. Followup questions like this cannot be answered in the comments